# 500 ERROR WHEN DEPLOYING THE ASP.NET MVC4 WEBSITE ON Windows 2003 machine running IIS 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web, web-deployment

I am having trouble when deploying the asp.net mvc on iis6 runing on windows 2003. Below is the case:
I have it running on a separate app pool and it is setup to use asp.net 4.0. I have a Wildcard application mapping to aspnet_isapi.dll which was required to get the page to appear.
But When I visit the site from another computer, the error happened and I just got the error code 500 inside the server's log file. I have no idea what to do. I already copy all the dlls needed to server(CopyLocal =true). When I type ipAddress/repairlist/index (repairlist is the name of my controller), I got the error. but when i type ipAddress/test.txt, it just display the content of the text.
What makes me feel puzzled is that I create a template website using visual studio 2010, and i deploy it on the server, it just worked. I feel so frustrated.
So, I wonder How to deal with the problem like this? How can I get the detail error information so I can make it work. The log file of the IIS just indicates the 500 0 0  error code. I already follow the basic step indicated by the google. How could the template website just work, and mine didn't?

Answer (score 0):

Tough although it *seems* it is an *ASP.Net* error - re: IIS is serving **text** file fine - don't confuse this with *ASP.Net application* - a text (`.txt`) file can be served by IIS *without* Asp.net.

Process of elimination:

- Just put up an `aspx` file - does nothing but return "Hello World" - this is just a check to see if ASP.net is configured properly (without any other dependency)

  - If the above works, then have you tried [`customErrors="Off"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.100).aspx)? This will hopefully give you enough error detail to track application errors (missing assemblies, db connections/strings, etc.)
  - Otherwise, it at least is pointing to ASP.net not configured properly (if it can't even serve a simple `aspx` page that only returns "hello world").

It's been a while for me (IIS 6) so maybe this will help:
[ASP.NET MVC on IIS 6 Walkthrough](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx/)

Hth.